# Showing taxonomy terms on custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, conditional-tags

I have a custom post type named movies and taxonomy is genres.
Now there's a movie "random" with genres "horror" "drama" "adventure"

What I want to do is: list all of the associated genres on that movie page and when you click on a genre it links to that genre page. How can I do that.

Answer (score 1):

You might have already figured this out, but here's an example how to get custom taxonomy terms for a post and create a list of links for the found terms.

```
// used in your custom post type template, e.g. single-movies.php
$genres = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'genres' );
// current post has genre terms attached to it
if ( $genres && ! is_wp_error( $genres ) ) {
  $term_links = array();
  // build list item links
  foreach ($genres as $genre) {
    $genre_links[] = sprintf(
      '<li><a href="%s">%s</a></li>',
      esc_url(get_term_link($genre->term_id, $genre->taxonomy)),
      esc_html($genre->name)
    );
  }
  // display genres link list
  printf(
    '<ul>%s</ul>',
    implode('', $genre_links)
  );
}
```